# MobileServiceClient InvokeApiAsync gets 401 while try to access asp.net core web api

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I have a Xamarin Forms app that intereacts with a Asp.net Core Web api hosted on Azure App Service with client authentication flow with Azure B2C authentication.

The app can login succesfully to the Azure with the LoginAsyc (I get the idtoken) but when I try to invoke a service that requires authorization using the MobileServiceClient I get a 401.  The api is called using the InvokeApiAsync.

If I invoke a an api method that does not require authorization it works fine.

I opened the Azure logs, and only see 401 error.

Any idea how to call this secure action method from Xamarin using the MobileServiceClient.

Please help

David

Answer (score 0):

> The app can login succesfully to the Azure with the **LoginAsyc** (I get the **idtoken**) but when I try to invoke a service that requires authorization using the MobileServiceClient I get a 401. The api is called using the InvokeApiAsync.

According to your description, I assumed that you are using [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview). For [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow), you directly contact the AAD  identity provider and retrieve the id_token or access_token. At this time, you could just access the authorized endpoint as follows:

```
https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/values
Authorization: Bearer {aad id_token or access_token}
```

**Note:** When constructing the `MobileServiceClient`, you could pass your custom `DelegatingHandler` to append the bearer token before sending request(s) to your Azure backend.

I just created a single Native app in my B2C tenant and use MSAL to retrieve the id_token or access_token as follows:

```
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{Tenant}/{Policy}";
PublicClientApplication IdentityClientApp = new PublicClientApplication("{native-app-id}", authority);
IdentityClientApp.RedirectUri = $"msal{native-app-id}://auth";

var scopes = new string[] {
        //"https://bruceb2c.onmicrosoft.com/EasyAuthB2CApp/user.read"
        ""
    };

var result=await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
```

**Note:** I just created a single native app, the parameter `scopes` in `AcquireTokenAsync` method does not support the clientId, so I just pass the empty scopes, at this point, you would not receive the access_token, you just need to use the `id_token` as the bearer token to access your Web API. For the Web API web app, I used the native app to configure my AD authentication on Azure Portal.

Moreover, you could create a native aad app for your mobile client and a WebAPI aad app for your azure web app. At this time, you could specify the valid scopes for your native aad app to access the WebAPI app. Then, you would retrieve the access_token, at this time you need to set the WebAPI app id as the Client ID or add it to the **ALLOWED TOKEN AUDIENCES** list on Azure Portal.

In summary, you need to make sure the `aud` property in the `id_token` or `access_token` matches your Azure Active Directory Authentication Settings on Azure Portal. **Note:** You could use https://jwt.io/ to decode the token and check the related properties.

Moreover, for client flow authentication using `LoginAsync`, you need to pass the access_token to log in with your web app, then you would retrieve the `authenticationToken`. And the mobile client library would add the `authenticationToken` as the `x-zumo-auth` header to the subsequent requests (e.g. using `MobileServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync`).

Additionally, here are some tutorials, you could refer to them:

[App Service Auth and Azure AD B2C](https://cgillum.tech/2016/05/27/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c/)

[Integrate Azure AD B2C into a Xamarin forms app using MSAL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native)

[Azure AD B2C: Requesting access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens)

[ASP.NET Core 2.0 web API with Azure AD B2C using JWT Bearer middleware](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi)